# How to remove unwanted tunnel adapter connections?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking

I did "ipconfig" today and found about 10 network interfaces, most of them disconnected.

How can I diagnose this? Where can I remove them?

**Edit**:

The extra network appear like this:

> Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection*
>   16
>
> Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection*
>   17
>
> Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection*
>   18

...

Comment: Are you running any Virtual Machines?  Do you have VPN connections set up to the workplace etc?

Comment: might very well be due to VPN indeed. I've seen pcs with over hundred of these, not sure why, must be a bad configuration.

Comment: @Joe, @stijn, No special VPN configuration that I'm aware of

Comment: You probably should change the title something like: _How to remove unwanted tunnel adapter connections?_ Since the real question is about removing the connection? Instead of why are they there.

Comment: This is why I asked you to change the title. [How to remove unwated tunnel adapter? Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=How+to+remove+unwated+tunnel+adapter%3F). Your question is listed as #1 now.

Answer (score 24):

#### How to remove the unwanted Tunnel Adapters via Device Manager:

(*This solution has been tested and confirmed to work*)

- Open **Start Menu**
- Type In: *Device Manager*
- Select **Device Manager**
- Click the **View** menu from the top
- Select **Show Hidden Devices** (*Must be check before continuing*)
- Scroll down and expand **Network Adapters**
- Right-Click a duplicated **Microsoft 6to4 Adapter** or **Microsoft ISATAP Adapter**
- Select **Uninstall**
- Click **OK** for the pop-up warning message
- Repeat and repeat for each of the unwanted duplicated adapter
- Close **Device Manager** when finish

*Credit: Microsoft Answer's Moderator Nicholas Li per this [**post**](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistanetworking/thread/32b0c129-fa2d-431a-a275-4288c729605a/).*

*Warning: It's always a good idea to create system restore point before making any systems changes.*

---

#### So what is tunnel adapter?

Tunneling is how to do secure communications across an untrusted network such as the internet. If you look at "description" of each connection, via `ipconfig /all`, it will probably the contain either [**ISATAP**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISATAP) or [**6over4**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6over4). Find information about [**Tunnel Adapters**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol) at Wikipedia.

Comment: I don't see "Network Connections" link from Network and Sharing Center. Also, I only see two wireless networks from "Manage Wireless Networks", and one of them I use at work.

Comment: See my edit about Tunnel adapter

Comment: I updated my answer. I also fix the step to Manage Network Connections.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I remove them?

Comment: Answer updated. I have tested it and confirmed that this works.

Answer (score 7):

These adapters are part of the Microsoft implementation of the iPv6 TCP/IP address protocol. You will find you have quite a lot of them, at least one per each defined network adapter. You also probably have VMware player installed, which adds several network adapters potentially used by virtual machines.

These dummy adapters are called "Automatic Tunneling Pseudo-Interface" for encapsulating IPv6 packets with an IPv4 header so that they can be sent across an IPv4 network. This probably means that your local network is at the moment both iPv4 and iPv6, and these adapters are created "just in case".

If you are working on a local network, you have no need of iPv6, since 4-byte TCP/IP addresses are quite sufficient for the number of computers. To get rid of these dummy adapters do:

1. Open up Control Panel -> Network and Sharing Center.
2. For each network connection :

   - Click "View status", then Properties.
   - Uncheck the mark next to "Internet protocol version 6 (TCP/IPv6)".
   - Click OK, then Close.
3. When all adapters are done, reboot.

This will leave only iPv4 interfaces defined on your computer, and will only work if you do not have any pure-iPv6 device on the local network. If you do have such a device, you will need to allow iPv6 at least on the one network adapter on which it communicates.

Comment: This answer tells how to completely disable IPv6.  It does not tell how to disable only the tunnelling network adapters. In an environment with IPv6 connectivity you'd want to leave IPv6 enabled, but probably disable the tunneling adapters.

Comment: @DanPritts: IPv6 in local networks is very rarely or never an issue, and almost no computer is nowadays directly connected to the Internet. IPv6 can almost always be dispensed with (except for routers connecting to the Internet), and disabling it is also the solution for several other problems found on this forum.

Comment: This isn't true.  Lots of universities and government sites use IPv6, and more every day.  So disabling IPv6 isn't necessarily the right answer in every case.  Regardless, it is *not* an answer to the question that is posed - which is how to disable  the tunnelling adapters.

Also, if your local site isn't running ipv6, then your router doesn't have any use for it either.

Comment: @DanPritts: It is an answer because **it solves the problem with the least amount of work, MUCH more economical than the accepted answer**. IPv6: ISPs need it, as the Internet is the only world network that is running out of IPv4 addresses. For any internal network, 32 bits for IPv4 addresses are much more than enough. Exposing local IPv6 addresses to the Internet can expose internal network architecture if done with ignorance, so is a security risk.

Comment: I'm well aware of the reasons for IPv6 and the IPv4 address exhaustion situation.  This is why I made a point of commenting here; people ARE starting to use IPv6.   Regarding ISPs, it's not much use for your ISP to be using IPv6 if the customers on their network aren't.  (The exception is for huge networks which use IPv6 for their own internal management, e.g., comcast).  Regardless, i'll stop now; anyone reading this can make their own decision.

Comment: @DanPritts: Last comment: The router will use [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) to convert local IPv4 addresses to Internet IPv6 when required (I remark that many ISPs still use IPv4). I suspect that this misunderstanding of the interplay between local-network/router/ISP has contributed to my answer not being very popular, so I went to some length to answer your comment.

Comment: Disabling IPv6 in this way is not supported by Microsoft. Instead it should be disabled as follows: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/929852/guidance-for-configuring-ipv6-in-windows-for-advanced-users

Comment: @Minkus: That's how it is done by registry updates. It's safer to use the graphical interface, as the registry may change in the future.

Comment: @harrymc It's not. There are many issues documented throughout the Microsoft website with disabling IPv6 by unbinding it. For example:
https://windorks.wordpress.com/2014/02/24/known-issues-with-disabling-or-unbinding-ipv6/
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/yongrhee/2018/02/28/stop-hurting-yourself-by-disabling-ipv6-why-do-you-really-do-it-2/
That's why the site I referenced states: 'We recommend that you use “Prefer IPv4 over IPv6” in prefix policies instead of disabling IPV6.'
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/929852/guidance-for-configuring-ipv6-in-windows-for-advanced-users

Comment: @Minkus: Complications are apparently possible, but I have never encountered them. On the other hand, I have encountered quite a few posts here where the solution was to disable IPv6, although on local networks. Thanks for pointing out these possible problems - they might arrive more in the future, as IPv4 addresses are now exhausted.

Answer (score 7):

From the command line:

```
netsh interface ipv6 6to4 set state state=disabled undoonstop=disabled
netsh interface ipv6 isatap set state state=disabled
netsh interface teredo set state disabled
```

If you're running Windows 2012/8 or later, you can do it with powershell:

```
Set-Net6to4configuration -state disabled
Set-Netisatapconfiguration -state disabled
Set-NetTeredoConfiguration -type disabled
```

Caveat - if for some reason you want the tunnel adapters on some, but not all, of your interfaces, this isn't the right solution.  Probably that's not what you want though.

Credit & more information about what these adapters are: http://www.minasi.com/newsletters/nws1303.htm

Comment: Brilliant answer, this is just perfect. Out of curiosity, I wonder about the three different syntaxes for the three disables....

Comment: Yeah, I wonder too.  Especially the powershell ones, you'd think they would be consistent.

Comment: The only thing consistent about Windows commands is their inconsistency!