# Remove a proxy/tunnel from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, proxy

My Windows 7 desktop recently started refusing https connections in a lot of applications, e.g Firefox works fine but IE9 can't visit an https page. Since I only tend to use the effected applications intermittently I can't pinpoint the exact time the issue started except that it began within the last week.

Fiddler claims the traffic is going through a tunnel which makes me think it's probably related to an update of [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/). I have tried

1. Repairing Virtual Box
2. Uninstalling Virtual Box
3. Turning off all firewalls
4. Removing tunnel adapters as in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/218278/how-to-remove-unwanted-tunnel-adapter-connections)
5. Changing proxy settings in the Internet Options to Automatic (they reset back to "Use proxy server" on restart, I have no proxy set up)
6. Ran a virus scan using a paid version of Avira already installed and with up-to-date definitions.
7. My laptop is working fine so my connection beyond the borders of my box is working as expected.

I am out of ideas. Is there anything else I can try?

**Edit** Added 6 & 7. The issue is with the host machine, I included the Virtual Box tag only because its update might have been the source of the issue. Here is what `ipconfig /all` has to say with Virtual Box installed.

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : HAL9008D
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek RTL8168C(P)/8111C(P) Family PCI-E
 Gigabit Ethernet NIC (NDIS 6.20) #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1F-D0-27-42-29
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek RTL8168C(P)/8111C(P) Family PCI-E
 Gigabit Ethernet NIC (NDIS 6.20)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1F-D0-27-42-2B
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::846a:d76e:3f30:c2c8%14(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.141(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, August 23, 2012 4:40:44 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, August 25, 2012 3:49:00 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 167780304
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-14-1D-96-6E-00-1F-D0-27-42-2B

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 08-00-27-00-5C-EB
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::384e:c00e:b945:7d21%18(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 419954727
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-14-1D-96-6E-00-1F-D0-27-42-2B

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{E5EDFA3C-ABA4-461A-B654-468594C12BA9}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{65EFE58D-41CA-4CA6-B847-408AA1063534}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{FE1C4745-7FA9-4D8C-AFB0-D63447C88E37}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: What about the date-time in your guest? Is it set correctly? (with timezone too)

Comment: This is on the computer that hosts the virtual machine, not the guest operating system.

Comment: Well, the same applies! :)

Comment: The date/time is set correctly but it was off by 4 minutes and I updated it within the time period when the issue started occurring. I also changed the time server from time.windows.com to time.nist.gov

Comment: Is it in the realm of possibility that your ISP is blocking your HTTPS connections?

Comment: HTTPS connections work under Firefox. For applications that don't work, Fiddler claims the connection is opened without data ever being sent by my computer. This implies to me that it is an issue with my computer's settings and not with my internet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the nuclear option: Reinstalling Windows.

Answer (score 2):

check to make sure that the host does not have a virus.  Its not unusual for some viruses to proxy to 127.0.0.0.1:...  see if there is a default gateway set on the virtualbox's interface on the host.  the only defaultGW should be to the internet connection.

If fiddler or another app can pinpoint what port it is using see what application is running on that port.

Comment: I have run a virus scan, it came back negative and I don't see any processes or services currently running that I don't recognize. That isn't to say there isn't a virus but the likelihood is lower. The Virtual Box host is showing no gateways set up in its preferences.

Comment: Amusingly enough, the internet, HTTP and HTTPS both, works perfectly from within a Virtual Machine. Only the host operating system seems to be following its own proxy or whatever settings.

Comment: @BryanAnderson - You can check your computer via ESET's online scan. That's the safest. Warning: It may take a couple of hours if you run it on the highest setting. http://www.eset.com/us/online-scanner/